# Unable to run map reduce job in hadoop 2.7 - Type Mismatch

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

While running the program getting `Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable`

I tried more suggestions from google / stack sites. But no luck. Still getting same exception. Any idea, where / what I have missed?

My Imports

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
```

My Map class

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
{
    Text k = new Text();


    public void map(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context) 
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString(); 
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line," "); 
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
            String year= tokenizer.nextToken();
            k.set(year);
            String temp= tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
            int v = Integer.parseInt(temp); 
            context.write(k,new IntWritable(v)); 
        }
    }
}
```

And my reduce class

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{

    public void reduce (Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int maxtemp=0;
        for(IntWritable it : values) {
            int temperature= it.get();
            if(maxtemp<temperature)
            {
                maxtemp =temperature;
            }
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxtemp)); 
    }
}
```

And main

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

Job job = new Job(conf, "MaxTemp");
job.setJarByClass(MaxTemp.class);
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

(I have compiled this code with Java 7 in Eclipse IDE (Mars) - exported as runnable jar and Hadoop version is 2.7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an `@Override` annotation to your `map` function you'll find it doesn't override the `map` method in `Mapper`.

If you look at the Javadoc for Mapper ([link here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)) you'll find the `map` method should look like:

`map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)`

where as yours looks like

`map(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context)`

So yours should be:

`map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)`

So because you aren't actually overriding the base `map` class in `Mapper`, your method isnt being called an its using the one in `Mapper` which looks like:

```
protected void map(KEYIN key, VALUEIN value, 
                     Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    context.write((KEYOUT) key, (VALUEOUT) value);
}
```

This will be taking in `LongWritable` and `Text` and writting them back out (Identity Mapper) which doesnt match the `Text` and `IntWritable` you've told it they should be.

In your driver these lines:

```
job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
```

Should be more like:

```
job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
```

You need to use your implementations not the base classes.

Comment: tried annotation before i posted the code, didn't work. And modified ``map`` signature too. still no luck.

Comment: @Spike - added an update for you since the driver is also wrong.

Comment: @Nerd, after driver change getting ``Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mine.md3.MaxTemp$Map not found``. Class files are there in the jar. But, there are some other code also there in my project. Will it be a problem?

Comment: What did you change `setMapperClass` to and is your `Map` inside another class? Assuming its inside another class you probably need something like `setMapperClass(SOMETHING$Map.class)` (its a static inner class).

Comment: Yes, its inside class ``MaxTemp``.

Comment: If main is inside MaxTemp, setting it to Map.class should work.

Comment: I have modified as ``job.setMapperClass(Map.class); job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);`` . If i tried to set mainclass with inner class getting compilation error. Can you just paste the exact syntax, how it suppose to be?

Comment: Finally it worked with your steps along with adding ``job.setJar("mtemp.jar");`` (my exported jar name). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapper definition `public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>` defines Key is `LongWritable` and value `Text`.

However your map method `public void map(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context)` defines `Text` as key and `Iterable<IntWritable>` as value.

Hence your map method should be defined as `public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)`

Comment: I tried this, but did't work. ``public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException``. getting same exception.

Comment: Does adding "Override" as suggested by "Binary Nerd", tells you that you correctly overridden the map method ?